# How could colors be encoded in these values?

Tags: binary-diagnosis

I've got a number of colors which I'm trying to reverse engineer from a binary blob.

I've narrowed it down to a small section of the file, with the following values:

`c[(0,0,0)] =      0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
c[(1,1,1)] =      0xBF0E01554E8BA53F00000000000000000000000000000000
c[(2,2,2)] =      0x28669E4C5AC1C23F00000000000000000000000000000000
c[(254,254,254)]= 0x8026349E84EE584000000000000000000000000000000000
c[(255,255,255)]= 0x00000000000059400000000000000000000000000000193D
c[(1,0,0)] =      0x77AD31D28614853FAC4E7111AF220640D52D4FEF829A0340
c[(0,1,0)] =      0x8B4660320FF59C3F5148F95093550AC032ACE29C3D4A0540
c[(0,0,1)] =      0xCE01487450BA6C3F281E4AB53579044013312C6B12540DC0
c[(255,0,0)] =    0xE01C58AC04464C40091768519039534082A2B8D49E065140
c[(0,255,0)] =    0x46F3DD4DDA665540BAD424C91DDF56C05E7592BA947D5240
c[(0,0,255)]=     0xD84DBD3AA1554140BF17BD2D09C85140F9DB813DD37859C0`

I'm looking for tips in how to decode these strings to the corresponding color strings.

Answer (score 2):

Worked it out - the colors are encoded using the CIELAB color model. They are represented as a sequence of 3 8-byte, little endian doubles, corresponding to the C, I and E components of the color.